# Computing 1D Ising model partition function, with fixed number of up spins

Tags: combinatorics

I wish to estimate the partition function of the 1D Ising model on a line (i.e. open boundary conditions):

$$
Z(\beta) := \sum_{\left(\sigma_j\right)_{0 \leq j < n} \in \{1, -1\}^n}\exp\left(\beta\sum_{0 \leq j < n}\sigma_j\sigma_{j + 1}\right)
$$

with the amendment that one restricts the number of $+1$ spins to, say, $w$:

$$
Z_w(\beta) := \sum_{\substack{\left(\sigma_j\right)_{0 \leq j < n} \in \{1, -1\}^n\\\sum\limits_{0 \leq j < n}\frac{1 + \sigma_j}{2} = w}}\exp\left(\beta\sum_{0 \leq j < n}\sigma_j\sigma_{j + 1}\right)
$$

In the first case (the usual model), the partition function sum can easily be expressed as the matrix-vector product:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\beta} & e^{-\beta}\\
e^{-\beta} & e^{\beta}
\end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix},
$$

which evaluates to $2\left(2\cosh(\beta)\right)^n$.

I am now wondering about the case where the number of up spins is restricted.

I have not found explicit results in the literature for that case, so I would first be grateful if someone could point any!

Next, I have tried to attack the problem by introducing a (complex) field in the partition function and recovering the desired quantity by discrete Fourier transform. Explicitly, defining:

$$
\hat{Z}_{k}(\beta) := \sum_{\left(\sigma_j\right)_{0 \leq j < n} \in \{1, -1\}^n}\exp\left(\beta\sum_{0 \leq j < n}\sigma_j\sigma_{j + 1} + \frac{2\pi i k}{n}\sum_{0 \leq j < n}\frac{1 + \sigma_j}{2}\right),
$$

the restricted partition function can be written:

$$
Z_{w}(\beta) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{0 \leq k < n}\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi ikw}{n}\right)\hat{Z}_k(\beta)
$$

As for the "Fourier-transformed" restricted partition function $\hat{Z}_k(\beta)$, it can be expressed as a matrix-vector product similar to the usual 1D Ising case:

$$
\hat{Z}_k(\beta) = (-1)^k\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{i\pi k}{2n}}\\
e^{-\frac{i\pi k}{2n}}
\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\beta}e^{i\pi k/n} & e^{-\beta}\\
e^{-\beta} & e^{\beta}e^{-i\pi k/n}
\end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{i\pi k}{2n}}\\
e^{-\frac{i\pi k}{2n}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

These formulae make numerical calculations feasible, but I now wish to get further analytic understanding. For the application I have in mind, I am rather interested by the case $\beta \in \pm\frac{i\pi}{2} + \mathbf{R}$ and $w \approx \frac{n}{2}$ (half of spins up), but any insight in other regimes could also help.

For instance, I conjecture that in the case $\beta \in \pm\frac{i\pi}{2} + \mathbf{R}$, $e^{-\beta n}\hat{Z}_w(\beta)$ looks "smooth" around $w = \frac{n}{2}$, which suggests some approximation by a real-variable function could be possible. However, I am not sure how to prove that at the moment, since the expression of $e^{-\beta n}Z_{n/2}(\beta)$ as a Fourier transform:
$$
e^{-\beta n}Z_{n/2}(\beta) = e^{-\beta n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0 \leq j < n}\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi ik \cdot (n/2)}{n}\right)\hat{Z}_k(\beta).
$$
appears highly oscillatory from numerical experiments.

Thanks for your insights!